# mongoose Schema array of 2 mixed object inside

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, jsonschema

hey I'm trying to do an array into an array and both of them are mixed types, thats how I built it

```
var Fields = new Schema({
        type: {type: String},
        length: {type: Number},
        lable: {type: String},
        name: {type: String}
});

var Fieldsets = new Schema({
        label: {type: String},
        name: {type: String},
        fields: {type: [Fields]}
});

var Steps = new Schema({
    order: {type: Number},
    name: {type: String},
    fieldsets: {type: [Fieldsets]}
});

var FormSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true  
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    steps: {type: [Steps]}
});
```

then im using this, via postman (chrome extension) to post this

```
{
    "name": "Reg Form",
    "steps": [
        {
            "order": "1",
            "name": "Login Information",
            "fieldsets": {
                "label": "Username and password",
                "name": "username_password",
                "fields": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "length": "256",
                    "lable": "Username",
                    "name": "username"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "order": "2",
            "name": "Check check",
            "fieldsets": {
                "label": "Email and age",
                "name": "email_age",
                "fields": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "length": "256",
                    "lable": "email",
                    "name": "email"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

the result is like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "534964bd55da09f8144d43ac",
    "__v": 0,
    "steps": [],
    "created": "2014-04-12T16:07:25.780Z",
    "name": "Reg Form"
  }
]
```

why is that ?

im trying to make an array of **Steps** which includes inside **Fieldsets** which include inside  **Fields** and I dont understand why it isnt going on.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm brand new to this but try instead of `steps: { type: [ Steps ]  }`  doing `steps: [ Steps ]` and the same with fields